# Lenovo P71 Windows 10 Pro Upgrade from 20H2 to 21H1 fails with Intel RST: The inbox storage driver iastora.sys doesn't work on these systems

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, intel-rst

Trying to upgrade Windows 10 Pro from 20H2 to 21H1, actually trying to fix another issue ([Lenovo P71 (Windows 10, NVidia M620 graphics card) with an external Dell U3818DW 21:9 monitor changes resolution between system restarts (too small)](https://superuser.com/questions/1663633/lenovo-p71-windows-10-nvidia-m620-graphics-card-with-an-external-dell-u3818dw)), results in:

[image]

Error:

[image]

I downloaded and installed some Intel RST drivers that seemed to match, however I still get the same error message over and over again, preventing me to upgrade.

Device manager (sorry, it's all German):

[image]

**EDIT 1**:

I tried to uninstall the SATA AHCI Controller device according to https://www.howtoedge.com/fix-update-fail-bsod-error-iastora-sys-on-windows-10/ but I still get the same error.

**QUESTION/S**:

How do I make the upgrade pass?

What's the driver needed for anyway, given that my storage device is a Samsung? Is it something else?

How do I find the correct driver blocking the Windows 10 Upgrade??

Comment: That driver is not for the Samsung storage device. It is for the SATA controller integrated in the Intel chipset.

Comment: Please provide us the logs from SetupDiag. The logs will have to be English for them to be helpful.  Furthermore, the error message is pretty clear, Intel RST is the problem.  Unless you have Windows installed while in RAID mode you don't necessarily need Intel RST installed.  [Have you considered just installing the 21H1 enablement package?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5000736-featured-update-to-windows-10-version-21h1-by-using-an-enablement-package-75a01e67-3b5f-4677-8efe-42852e41c7cf).  It's unnecessary to use Windows Setup to upgrade to 21H1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 3 things with this driver:

All are referenced here:

[Intel RST](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000027232/technologies/intel-rapid-storage-technology-intel-rst.html)

**Solution One** – Reset the Startup Intel® RST Service. Find this in Services.

**Solution Two** – Update the Intel® RST driver.  Either in Device Manager or via Lenovo System Update / Vantage. You can also look in the Intel Download Centre for your specific model of laptop.

**Three:**  Uninstall the Driver.  Select Device Manager.
Find and expand the **Disk drives** catalog. Right-click on Intel® Rapid Storage Technology and choose Uninstall device.

If none of the above (specifically 3 - uninstall) work,  you may need to try a Window 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Uninstalling the driver: delete the driver? I uninstalled the driver without deleting, then restarted the upgrade process (see EDIT 1), but this didn't work.

Comment: Try the Repair Install step and use the option to Keep Everything to begin with. That will re-install drivers along the way except for BIOS

Comment: There was a new, optional 21H1 update out today that (on two machines) ran through the install step twice, and did the two step restart. I would get your machine working correctly so these updates can proceed without error.

Comment: I was finally able to upgrade Windows 10 to 21H1 via this link: https://borncity.com/win/2021/07/30/windows-10-vorbereitungsupdate-kb4023057-juli-2021/ There's another link there to the MS site, that seemed to bypass the Intel RST problem. FWIW: I also installed some "ThinkPad Video Features (NVidia N17) Driver" via the Lenovo website, but my original screen resolution problem (see link at the very top) is still present. Thanks to everybody for helping with the Windows Update problem!